# Pytorch Architecture Failure

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to build my own resent architecture.
I have the following Resent Architecture:

```
ResNetClassifier(
  (feature_extractor): Sequential(
    (0): ResidualBlock(
      (main_path): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (1): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (4): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (5): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (6): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (7): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (8): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (9): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (10): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (11): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (12): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (13): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (14): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (15): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (16): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (17): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (18): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (19): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (20): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      )
      (shortcut_path): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    )
    (1): ResidualBlock(
      (main_path): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (1): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (4): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (5): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (6): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (7): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (8): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (9): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (10): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (11): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (12): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (13): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (14): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (15): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (16): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (17): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (18): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (19): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (20): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      )
      (shortcut_path): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    )
    (2): ResidualBlock(
      (main_path): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (1): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (4): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (5): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (6): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (7): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (8): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (9): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (10): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (11): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (12): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (13): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (14): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (15): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (16): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (17): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (18): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (19): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (20): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      )
      (shortcut_path): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    )
    (3): ResidualBlock(
      (main_path): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (1): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (4): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (5): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (6): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (7): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (8): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (9): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (10): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (11): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (12): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (13): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (14): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (15): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (16): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (17): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (18): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (19): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (20): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      )
      (shortcut_path): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    )
    (4): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
    (5): ResidualBlock(
      (main_path): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (1): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (4): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (5): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (6): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (7): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (8): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (9): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (10): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (11): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (12): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (13): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (14): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (15): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (16): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (17): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (18): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (19): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (20): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      )
      (shortcut_path): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    )
    (6): ResidualBlock(
      (main_path): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (1): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (4): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (5): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (6): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (7): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (8): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (9): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (10): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (11): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (12): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (13): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (14): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (15): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (16): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (17): Dropout2d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        (18): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (19): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
        (20): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      )
      (shortcut_path): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    )
  )
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=518400, out_features=100, bias=True)
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
    (2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=100, bias=True)
    (3): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
    (4): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
)
```

when sending tensor in size torch.Size([1, 3, 100, 100])
with the following code

```
net = cnn.ResNetClassifier(
    in_size=(3,100,100), out_classes=10, channels=[32, 64]*3,
    pool_every=4, hidden_dims=[100]*2,
    activation_type='lrelu', activation_params=dict(negative_slope=0.01),
    pooling_type='avg', pooling_params=dict(kernel_size=2),
    batchnorm=True, dropout=0.1,
)
print(net)

torch.manual_seed(seed)

test_image = torch.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(3, 100, 100), dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(0)
test_out = net(test_image)
print('out =', test_out)
```

it fails with following error:

"RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 64, 100, 100] to have 3 channels, but got 64 channels instead"

Any clue to solve it will be appreciated!

BTW, what is the recommended way to debug such network errors?

Comment: can you share the code.

Comment: According to the error, the input dimensions are *not* [1,3,100,100] but instead [1,64,100,100]. So check your input and/or share more code.

Comment: I added the code, the input is indeed [1,3,100,100]